# Input data from one workbook form into another workbooks worksheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, vba, microsoft-excel-2007

**What I am trying to achieve:**

I have one workbook with an application form to request additional training.  A person fills out all the cells on the form and clicks submit.

I then want all the data from the custom form to be input into another sheet in another workbook.

I am currently using the below code which does correctly copy all the data into another worksheet....in the same workbook, but I ideally need it to open another workbook and put the data into a sheet there.  I've seen people post a few similar solutions but none are tailored to my needs.

Does anyone know how I would adapt the below code that I have written, to instead of copying to a sheet in the same workbook, copy to another worksheet in a separate workbook.

```
Sub Submit()
'Declaring all variables
Dim TrainingSummary As String, RequestedBy As String, DeliveryMethod As String, DateRequested As Date, DueDate As Date, EmailAddress As String, Department As String, StartDate As Date, Approval As String
Dim ApprovalName As String, Headcount As Integer, TrainingDescription As String, AdditionalNotes As String, MaterialRequired As String

'Selecting my training request form sheet and then setting the contents of the cells to the variables
Worksheets("Training Request").Select
TrainingSummary = Range("E5")
DeliveryMethod = Range("E23")
RequestedBy = Range("E5")
DueDate = Range("E19")
DateRequested = Range("E15")
EmailAddress = Range("E7")
Department = Range("E9")
StartDate = Range("E17")
Approval = Range("E21")
ApprovalName = Range("H21")
MaterialRequired = Range("E25")
Headcount = Range("H23")
TrainingDescription = Range("C28")
AdditionalNotes = Range("C37")

'Selecting the worksheet I want to move the contents to and making sure entry always goes on a clear row
Worksheets("Pending Authorisation").Select
Worksheets("Pending Authorisation").Range("C3").Select
If Worksheets("Pending Authorisation").Range("C3").Offset(1, 0) <> "" Then
Worksheets("Pending Authorisation").Range("C3").End(xlDown).Select
End If

'Selecting and setting content in new rows
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
ActiveCell.Value = TrainingSummary
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
ActiveCell.Value = DeliveryMethod
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
ActiveCell.Value = MaterialRequired
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
ActiveCell.Value = RequestedBy
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
ActiveCell.Value = Department
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
ActiveCell.Value = DateRequested
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
ActiveCell.Value = StartDate
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
ActiveCell.Value = DueDate
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
ActiveCell.Value = Approval
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
ActiveCell.Value = Headcount
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
ActiveCell.Value = "Pending"
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
ActiveCell.Value = TrainingDescription
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
ActiveCell.Value = AdditionalNotes

'reselecting the original form sheet and clearing
Worksheets("Training Request").Select
Worksheets("Training Request").Range("E5:I9").ClearContents
Worksheets("Training Request").Range("E13:E25").ClearContents
Worksheets("Training Request").Range("C28:M32").ClearContents
Worksheets("Training Request").Range("H21:H23").ClearContents
Worksheets("Training Request").Range("C37:M41").ClearContents
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to resolve the issue by opening up the workbook I wanted to copy to and it selected the correct cells. I then put a close and save command so the workbook basically opens itself, transfers the information and closes.

```
Sub Submit()
'Declaring all variables
Dim TrainingSummary As String, RequestedBy As String, DeliveryMethod As String, DateRequested As Date, DueDate As Date, EmailAddress As String, Department As String, StartDate As Date, Approval As String
Dim ApprovalName As String, Headcount As Integer, TrainingDescription As String, AdditionalNotes As String, MaterialRequired As String

'Selecting my training request form sheet and then setting the contents of the cells to the variables
Worksheets("Training Request").Select
TrainingSummary = Range("E13")
DeliveryMethod = Range("E23")
RequestedBy = Range("E5")
DueDate = Range("E19")
DateRequested = Range("E15")
EmailAddress = Range("E7")
Department = Range("E9")
StartDate = Range("E17")
Approval = Range("E21")
ApprovalName = Range("H21")
MaterialRequired = Range("E25")
Headcount = Range("H23")
TrainingDescription = Range("C28")
AdditionalNotes = Range("C37")

Workbooks.Open ("Training Offline Priorities.xlsm")
Workbooks("Training Offline Priorities.xlsm").Activate
'Selecting the worksheet I want to move the contents to and making sure entry always goes on a clear row
Worksheets("Pending Authorisation").Select
Worksheets("Pending Authorisation").Range("C3").Select
If Worksheets("Pending Authorisation").Range("C3").Offset(1, 0) <> "" Then
Worksheets("Pending Authorisation").Range("C3").End(xlDown).Select
End If

'Selecting and setting content in new rows
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
ActiveCell.Value = TrainingSummary
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
ActiveCell.Value = DeliveryMethod
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
ActiveCell.Value = MaterialRequired
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
ActiveCell.Value = RequestedBy
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
ActiveCell.Value = Department
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
ActiveCell.Value = DateRequested
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
ActiveCell.Value = StartDate
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
ActiveCell.Value = DueDate
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
ActiveCell.Value = Approval
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
ActiveCell.Value = Headcount
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
ActiveCell.Value = "Pending"
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
ActiveCell.Value = TrainingDescription
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
ActiveCell.Value = AdditionalNotes
Workbooks("Training Offline Priorities.xlsm").Close SaveChanges:=True
Workbooks("Training Request Form.xlsm").Activate
'reselecting the original form sheet and clearing
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Training Request").Select
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Training Request").Range("E5:I9").ClearContents
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Training Request").Range("E13:E25").ClearContents
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Training Request").Range("C28:M32").ClearContents
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Training Request").Range("H21:H23").ClearContents
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Training Request").Range("C37:M41").ClearContents

End Sub
```

Training request represents my custom form.
Training Offline Priorities is the workbook I am copying into.
Pending authorisation is the sheet within the training offline priorities that receives the transferred data.

Figured i'd post the answer in case anyone had the same issue.

Comment: Seems both Code are similar !!

Comment: They are, its merely the opening, closing and activating of the sheets that made the difference.